# Probabilistic and/or defeasible reasoning in Protege?

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege, inference, reasoning

I have found some promising (old) articles but the trail has run cold.

Ideally I am looking for working plugins/code, but if they are simply not available, then any concrete directions on how to build probabilistic and/or defeasible reasoning for integration into Protege would still be useful.

- RaMP Defeasible Reasoning plugin for Protege. Appears to be dormant/abandoned. Perhaps project/code was lost along with http://code.google.com/p/nomor/
- PR-OWL http://www.pr-owl.org/. Extends OWL to support probabilistic ontologies. Appears to be dormant/abandoned.
- Defeasible RuleML looked interesting, but I cannot find any concrete implementations/plugins/code. http://ruleml.org/1.0/defeasible/defeasible.html.
- Defeasible Logic RuleML-compatible Rule
  Language. Even if code can be found, this implementation looks experimental, and does not leverage more recent standards and formats. Paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.103.5914&rep=rep1&type=pdf Resources: http://lpis.csd.auth.gr/systems/resources.html#drdchairruleml2010

Answer (score 1):

There's Pronto (available [here](https://github.com/klinovp/pronto)), which is built on top of Pellet. I cannot recall if it comes as a Protege plugin, but as it is tied to Pellet I imagine it shouldn't be too hard to implement an `OWLReasoner` wrapper for the two.

Comment: As far as I can see, the code is based on an old version of Pellet which itself is based on OWL API v3. Might lead to some conflicts

Comment: I gave it a bash to try and compile it with a newer OWLAPI, but this was a few years ago. Getting it to work on Protege 4.3 should be ok, Protege 5 a bit more challenging.